# Check if Browser's JS is enabled or disabled in backend code in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to check whether my browser's JS is enabled or disabled from server side and write the code according to that. I analysed many forums but all solutions are given in script side and to use  tag.  But for the performance base, i need to handle the code from server side. My page is aspx file. I need to handle it in aspx.cs file.

Example:

```
if(js is enabled){
asp control 1 display...
}

if(js is disabled){
asp control 2 display...
}
```

If js is enabled class js is adding and if js is disabled class no-js is adding in my html automatically.

Please help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't. Not without using the client somehow. The only one who knows if javascript is enabled on the client is.... the client. You'll have to send this information to the servert if you want to do anything with it on the server.

Comment: asp.net is a request-response based technology. think about it as letter-exchange. if you send a letter to your friend, how will you know if he is doing well unless he checks his situation and sends you a letter back?

Answer (score 1):

There is a class `System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities` which helps you to detect if JS is **supported** by the browser or not but not if it's **enabled or disabled**.

You can only detect it after the first page load via executing a script in the browser which sets **some flag in the cookie**. Then after a subsequent request, you can track if you want to render JS absent/present logic for that user.